# any existing protocol for accessing photos or pictures on a remote server

Tags: ios, iphone, linux, network-protocols, photos

I am trying to write a program (iPhone) to display some pictures (photos) from a linux server. I am investigating what protocol I should use.   Should i just use HTTP?  i.e. setting up a HTTP server on the linux server, and write a HTTP client on iPhone? Or,  is there a better protocol existing for such application (i.e. focused on photos / pictures transfer / show) ?

or, should I write my own protocol (using TCP or UDP of course) ?

update: Or, is there already a well-known Bonjour service for the same?

thanks.

Comment: HTTP is pretty standard for this sort of thing. And you won't have to write a client - iOS / Cocoa Touch includes HTTP client methods, and there are plenty of third-party libraries available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want allow to manipulate files, pay attention to the WebDAV protocol.

> WebDAV is an extension of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) that facilitates collaboration between users in editing and managing documents and files stored on World Wide Web servers.

Otherwise try to use SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol).